# How to close a pop up window and return control to parent page on successs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, popup

I am using this code.This pop up window pops up when I clicks a button on the main page.Now I want the pop up window to be closed if the password is successfully changed and reload the main page,but if the password is not changed then refresh the pop up window again.
Here is the code.....

```
<asp:Textbox id="curnt_paswrd" textmode="Password" runat="server" size="30" />
<asp:Textbox id="new_paswrd" textmode="Password" runat="server" size="30" />
```

Comment: This popup, is it simply just a new browser window that you open using window.open()?

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go....

This is for opening the popup....

```
<html> 
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var passwordPopup;

      function popUpPassword()
      {
        passwordPopup = window.open("ChangePassword.aspx");

        window.onbeforeunload = function()
        {
          alert("yay I reloaded!");
          window.onbeforeunload = null;
        }
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <button onclick="popUpPassword();">Popup Password Change</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And this for reloading the main page and closing popup....

```
public partial class ChangePassword : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

  protected void SubmitPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      bool passwordChanged = true;

      if (passwordChanged)
      {

        // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

        // Check to see if the client script is already registered.
        if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "popUpPwScript"))
        {
          StringBuilder jscript = new StringBuilder();
          jscript.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
          jscript.Append("window.opener.location.reload(); window.close();");
          jscript.Append("</script>");
          cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "popUpPwScript", jscript.ToString(), false);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        //do something else
      }
    }
}
```